# Add client search criteria Odoo13's POS

Tags: javascript, odoo, customization, pos, odoo-13

I've added some custom field's to the res.partner's model and I want to add this fields to the POS's search criteria. The fields I've added in my models.js file can be appreciated in the following code:

```js
odoo.define('my_module.models', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var models = require('point_of_sale.models');

    models.load_fields('res.partner', [
        'billing_name',
        'partner_billing_number'
    ]);

    models.load_models([{
        model: 'res.partner',
        fields: ['billing_name', 'partner_billing_number'],
        loaded: function(self, partners){self.db.add_partners(partners)},
    }]);

});
```

Then I've tried to add this fields to the search criteria with my db.js file with the following code:

```js
odoo.define('my_module.db', function (require) {
    "use strict";

    var core = require('web.core');

    var PosDB = core.Class.extend({
        _partner_search_string: function(partner){
            var str = partner.name || '';
            if(partner.billing_name){
                str += '|' + partner.billing_name;
            }
            if(partner.partner_billing_number){
                str += '|' + partner.partner_billing_number;
            }
            str = partner.id + ':' +str.replace(/:/g,'') + '\n';
            return str;
        },

        add_partners:function (partners) {
            for(let i=0, len=partners.length; i < len; i++){
                var partner = partners[i];
                var search_string = this._partner_search_string(partner);
                this.partner_search_string[partner] += search_string;
            }
        }
    });

    return PosDB;

});
```

So far I was not able to add both search fields to the search criteria, it even broke the code a bit. What is missing in my code? How can I achieve this?

Comment: Check 1st weather you are getting value of that field for particular customer record.

Comment: As I said, I wasn't able to add them to the search criteria because Odoo doesn't return the records I've created to test this code. You mean that this code block should work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
odoo.define('my_module.models', function (require) {
    "use strict";

var PosDB = require('point_of_sale.DB');
var models = require('point_of_sale.models');
models.load_fields('res.partner', [
        'billing_name',
        'partner_billing_number'
    ]);

PosDB.include({
    _partner_search_string: function(partner){
        var str =  partner.name || '';
        if(partner.barcode){
            str += '|' + partner.barcode;
        }
        if(partner.address){
            str += '|' + partner.address;
        }
        if(partner.phone){
            str += '|' + partner.phone.split(' ').join('');
        }
        if(partner.mobile){
            str += '|' + partner.mobile.split(' ').join('');
        }
        if(partner.email){
            str += '|' + partner.email;
        }
        if(partner.vat){
            str += '|' + partner.vat;
        }
        if(partner.billing_name){
            str += '|' + partner.billing_name;
        }
        if(partner.partner_billing_number){
            str += '|' + partner.partner_billing_number;
        }
        str = '' + partner.id + ':' + str.replace(':','') + '\n';
        return str;
    },
});

});
```

Use this only one file i hope you will get your required output.

Comment: Thanks guys I have been looking for it since this morning.